# Dumping a database table to text file

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008

I am trying to dump a table from MySQL database into a text file by running the following query

```
 SELECT fields FROM text_file_table INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\Program Files\\textfile.text'
```

But it gives me the error 
   **Cant create/write to file "C:\Program Files\textfile.text"**

I think it is due to security issue, that it is not allowing the DBMS to write the file on that directory. If there can be any other issue, please let me know, and also help me finding solution to the problem. And I am doing this on Windows Server 2008. Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you do `INTO OUTFILE `%temp%\\textfile.text` ?  On Win, %temp% is an env var that tells where the temp file directory is located.  You're right, MySQL may be resistant to letting users scribble stuff in Program Files.  I hope so.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two issues. The command runs in the operating system as 'mysql' so the 'mysql' user may not have permission to write in c:\Program Files. It shouldn't, so that's good. If you change your target path to somewhere that you can write to, this problem will go away.

The other issue is that the user you are logged in as inside mysql may not have the privilege to read and write files - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file. If this is the problem, you'll have to `GRANT` the privilege to your user.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with the path . if you are using windows

the filepath sould be like this in the query

```
'C:/Program Files/textfile.txt'
```

OR try this , i am not sure

```
'C:\Program Files\textfile.txt'
```

also use txt inside of text in the file name => `textfile.text`